# how to send a file with multiple threads in a basic FTP project

Tags: c++, c, linux

Now , i am writing a basic FTP to check out the result of my seif-learning. But i get a problem about how to send a file with multiple threads both in server and client. i use the memmap to map the article to the memeriy , but unfortuniturily , i have no idea about it. i need a detial . Right now , i just know cut the article into several pieces , and use different thread to read and send it in server, but i donot know what i should do in client and the basic steps.I hope you can give me some tips . Thanks .FYI: i am using ubuntu in c/c++.

Comment: I think you should make your own communication protocol, marking each packet, rearrangement rules. There should be open source code for your learning

Comment: your idea reminded me the basic rules of data fragment.thanks , but i could not be better if you recomment me some good open source web sites. i am a newbie. thanks

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with this field